# how to delete a message in tkinter after click

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to delete a message from tkinter. can you help me with it??

```
Label(root,text="Password : ").place(x=X+0,y=Y+170,in_=root)          #password to registor
reg_password=StringVar()
e5 = Entry(root,textvariable=reg_password).place(x=X+65,y=Y+170,in_=root)

m=Message(root,text='',fg="red").place(x=X+0,y=Y+250,in_=root)    
def sign_up():
    global m
    regpass = "^[A-Z][\w(!@#$%^&*_+?)+]{8,}$"
    if not (re.search(regpass,reg_password.get())):
        m.config(text='''->Spaces and empty sets are not allowed.
        \n ->First character should be a captial letter.
        \n ->Password must be greater than 8 character and must contain a special character.''')
    else:
        pass
```

if for the first time if password entered is wrong it will print the message and in the second time if the password is correct the message will be deleted

but it shows the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `place()` method doesn't return a value, so the statement:

```
m=Message(root,text='',fg="red").place(x=X+0,y=Y+250,in_=root)
```

assigns the value `None` to the variable `m`.

Split it up into two statements istead:

```
m = Message(root, text='', fg="red")
m.place(x=X+0, y=Y+250, in_=root)
```